# ipv6 connectivity problems

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6

I've got persistent ipv6 problems with my laptop running kubuntu 15.10 : download speed is very slow, and some transfer just end up totally stalled or timed out (ipv4 runs perfectly fine).

It's not a router or hardware problem, as the same laptop with a Live kubuntu 15.10 system runs ipv6 just fine. I've tried to run tests (simple wget on google.com or other websites) outside of X, with as few running processes as possible. I've tried to compare and change `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/*` values based on those of another kubuntu box. I've tried many different Network Manager connections configurations. No results. I've compared routes and `ifconfig` values with those of other working boxes, without seeing anything strange.

Here is a [wireshark capture output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkI2h.jpg) from a simple `wget -6 portail.free.fr` command :

[image]

Any idea of what could be done to fix this ?

Comment: Which kernel version are you having a problem with? Which kernel version is the live system using? Have you tried disabling `generic-receive-offload`?

Comment: I don't know how I couldn't try this... I switched back from kernel 4.3 to 4.2, and the problem seems solved. Your suggestion to turn off offloads seems to work with the 4.3 kernel too, at least for the wired interface. Many thanks. Is it a known 4.3 kernel problem ?

Comment: It seems the problem is known to you, I don't know if anybody else knows about it. When you see a difference between live system and installed system, then different package versions is the first thing to check for, and since TCP happens in the kernel there wasn't much doubt that it was kernel version to check for. And I could see from the capture that offloading was in effect, so turning it off was an obvious thing to try.

Comment: Well, thanks for your suggestion, and thanks for these explanations, too.